# MobileFirst 7.1.0.00.20170505-1403 - Intermittent connectivity issue to MobileFirst server from Android and iPhone

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

We have build an hybrid application and we have noticed an intermittent issue with connectivity to the mobile-first server from Android and iPhone. And it resolves once we kill the app and start again. This happens in following scenarios

1) when the direct update is requested and once the direct update is done immediately after that it stops working.
2) when the app is open and kept ideal in the background for some time like 30 min and then if try to access it does not connect to the server.

**iPhone Logs**

```
Jan 17 21:37:42 Owners-iPhone-3 MyMobileApp(CFNetwork)[5966] <Error>: NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1100
Jan 17 21:37:42 Owners-iPhone-3 locationd[71] <Notice>: {"msg":"CLWifiPositioningSystemLogic::apply", "event":"elapsed", "begin_mach":6677143475613, "end_mach":6677143529851, "elapsed_s":"0.002259917", "event":"Motion::CoarseMovement", "now_s":"537935862.468443036"}
Jan 17 21:37:43 Owners-iPhone-3 locationd[71] <Notice>: {"msg":"CLWifiPositioningSystemLogic::apply", "event":"elapsed", "begin_mach":6677159234428, "end_mach":6677159257208, "elapsed_s":"0.000949167", "event":"Motion::CoarseMovement", "now_s":"537935863.124722004"}
Jan 17 21:37:43 Owners-iPhone-3 MyMobileApp[5966] <Notice>: [DEBUG] [WORKLIGHT] +[WLClient sharedInstance] in WLClient.m:165 :: IBMMobilieFirstFoundation.framework version = 7.1-2016/09/19 17:15:50
Jan 17 21:37:43 Owners-iPhone-3 MyMobileApp[5966] <Notice>: [DEBUG] [My.SessionTimeoutServiceFactory] SessionTimeoutService elapsedTime :  NaN
Jan 17 21:37:43 Owners-iPhone-3 MyMobileApp[5966] <Notice>: [DEBUG] [My.services] {"wifiName":"Not Available","networkConnectionType":"WIFI","ipv4Addresses":{"3GAddress":"10.192.82.165","wifiAddress":"10.0.1.5"},"ipv6Addresses":{"3GAddress":"::2600:380:a32b:513d:40ac:e5f3","wifiAddress":"::fe80:8:0:0:1c1a:a8cf"},"isNetworkConnected":"true","carrierName":"Not Available","isRoaming":"Not Available","isAirplaneMode":"Not Available","telephonyNetworkType":"Not Available","ipAddress":"10.0.1.5"}
Jan 17 21:37:43 Owners-iPhone-3 MyMobileApp[5966] <Notice>: [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] +[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestWithURL:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:51 :: Request url is https://myServerIp:443/MyProject/adapters/AnnouncementsAdapter/announcements/fetchannouncements
Jan 17 21:37:43 Owners-iPhone-3 MyMobileApp[5966] <Notice>: [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper start] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:356 :: Starting the request with URL https://myServerIp:443/MyProject/adapters/AnnouncementsAdapter/announcements/fetchannouncements
Jan 17 21:37:43 Owners-iPhone-3 MyMobileApp(CFNetwork)[5966] <Error>: NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1001
Jan 17 21:37:43 Owners-iPhone-3 MyMobileApp(CFNetwork)[5966] <Error>: NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1001
Jan 17 21:37:43 Owners-iPhone-3 MyMobileApp[5966] <Notice>: [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:388 :: Request Failed
Jan 17 21:37:43 Owners-iPhone-3 MyMobileApp[5966] <Notice>: [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:389 :: Response Status Code : 0
Jan 17 21:37:43 Owners-iPhone-3 MyMobileApp[5966] <Notice>: [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:390 :: Response Error : The request timed out.
Jan 17 21:37:43 Owners-iPhone-3 MyMobileApp[5966] <Notice>: [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:388 :: Request Failed
Jan 17 21:37:43 Owners-iPhone-3 MyMobileApp[5966] <Notice>: [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:389 :: Response Status Code : 0
Jan 17 21:37:43 Owners-iPhone-3 MyMobileApp[5966] <Notice>: [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:390 :: Response Error : The request timed out.
Jan 17 21:37:43 Owners-iPhone-3 MyMobileApp(CFNetwork)[5966] <Notice>: TIC TCP Conn Cancel [39:0x1c4362700]
Jan 17 21:37:43 Owners-iPhone-3 MyMobileApp(CFNetwork)[5966] <Notice>: TIC TCP Conn Cancel [41:0x1c0365400]
Jan 17 21:37:43 Owners-iPhone-3 MyMobileApp(CFNetwork)[5966] <Notice>: TIC Enabling TLS [45:0x1c0368f40]
Jan 17 21:37:43 Owners-iPhone-3 MyMobileApp(CFNetwork)[5966] <Notice>: TIC TCP Conn Start [45:0x1c0368f40]
Jan 17 21:37:43 Owners-iPhone-3 MyMobileApp(CFNetwork)[5966] <Notice>: Task <8A3D00F0-37B8-4A43-BA2E-2C96EAE6AA9F>.<0> setting up Connection 45
Jan 17 21:37:44 Owners-iPhone-3 MyMobileApp(CFNetwork)[5966] <Notice>: TIC TLS Event [45:0x1c0368f40]: 1, Pending(0)
Jan 17 21:37:44 Owners-iPhone-3 locationd[71] <Notice>: {"msg":"CLWifiPositioningSystemLogic::apply", "event":"elapsed", "begin_mach":6677182200912, "end_mach":6677182224304, "elapsed_s":"0.000974667", "event":"Motion::CoarseMovement", "now_s":"537935864.081508040"}
Jan 17 21:37:44 Owners-iPhone-3 MyMobileApp(CFNetwork)[5966] <Notice>: TIC TLS Event [45:0x1c0368f40]: 2, Pending(0)
Jan 17 21:37:44 Owners-iPhone-3 MyMobileApp(CFNetwork)[5966] <Notice>: TIC TLS Event [45:0x1c0368f40]: 20, Pending(0)
Jan 17 21:37:44 Owners-iPhone-3 MyMobileApp(CFNetwork)[5966] <Notice>: TIC TCP Conn Connected [45:0x1c0368f40]: Err(16)
Jan 17 21:37:44 Owners-iPhone-3 MyMobileApp(CFNetwork)[5966] <Notice>: TIC TCP Conn Event [45:0x1c0368f40]: 1
Jan 17 21:37:44 Owners-iPhone-3 MyMobileApp(CFNetwork)[5966] <Notice>: TIC TCP Conn Event [45:0x1c0368f40]: 8
Jan 17 21:37:44 Owners-iPhone-3 MyMobileApp(CFNetwork)[5966] <Notice>: TIC TLS Handshake Complete [45:0x1c0368f40]
Jan 17 21:37:44 Owners-iPhone-3 MyMobileApp(CFNetwork)[5966] <Notice>: Task <8A3D00F0-37B8-4A43-BA2E-2C96EAE6AA9F>.<0> now using Connection 45
Jan 17 21:37:44 Owners-iPhone-3 MyMobileApp(CFNetwork)[5966] <Notice>: Task <8A3D00F0-37B8-4A43-BA2E-2C96EAE6AA9F>.<0> sent request, body N
Jan 17 21:37:44 Owners-iPhone-3 MyMobileApp(CFNetwork)[5966] <Notice>: Task <8A3D00F0-37B8-4A43-BA2E-2C96EAE6AA9F>.<0> received response, status 401 content K
Jan 17 21:37:44 Owners-iPhone-3 MyMobileApp(CFNetwork)[5966] <Notice>: Task <8A3D00F0-37B8-4A43-BA2E-2C96EAE6AA9F>.<0> response ended
Jan 17 21:37:44 Owners-iPhone-3 MyMobileApp[5966] <Notice>: [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:388 :: Request Failed
Jan 17 21:37:44 Owners-iPhone-3 MyMobileApp[5966] <Notice>: [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:389 :: Response Status Code : 401
Jan 17 21:37:44 Owners-iPhone-3 MyMobileApp[5966] <Notice>: [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:390 :: Response Error : Request failed: unauthorized (401)
Jan 17 21:37:44 Owners-iPhone-3 MyMobileApp[5966] <Notice>: [DEBUG] [WORKLIGHT] +[WLClient sharedInstance] in WLClient.m:165 :: IBMMobilieFirstFoundation.framework version = 7.1-2016/09/19 17:15:50
Jan 17 21:37:44 Owners-iPhone-3 MyMobileApp[5966] <Notice>: [DEBUG] [NONE] Request [https://myServerIp:443/MyProject/authorization/v1/authorization]
Jan 17 21:37:44 Owners-iPhone-3 trustd[5056] <Notice>: could not disable pinning: not an internal release
Jan 17 21:37:44 Owners-iPhone-3 MyMobileApp[5966] <Notice>: THREAD WARNING: ['WLAuthorizationManagerPlugin'] took '22.705078' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
Jan 17 21:37:44 Owners-iPhone-3 MyMobileApp[5966] <Notice>: [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] +[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestWithURL:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:51 :: Request url is https://myServerIp:443/MyProject/authorization/v1/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=4bd3c60d412b36d16f4da069658c0c7fa226cad1&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmfpredirecturi&isAjaxRequest=true&x=0.15013111462581286
Jan 17 21:37:44 Owners-iPhone-3 assertiond[74] <Notice>: Client relinquished <BKProcessAssertion: 0x100f8a9f0; "Called by UIKit, from <redacted>" (finishTask:180s); id:\M-b\M^@\M-&0B8CA7216A0C>
Jan 17 21:37:44 Owners-iPhone-3 assertiond[74] <Notice>: [MyMobileApp:5966] Deactivate assertion: <BKProcessAssertion: 0x100f8a9f0; "Called by UIKit, from <redacted>" (finishTask:180s); id:\M-b\M^@\M-&0B8CA7216A0C>
Jan 17 21:37:44 Owners-iPhone-3 assertiond[74] <Notice>: [MyMobileApp:5966] dump all assertions HWM:4 (deactivateAssertion): {
    <BKProcessAssertion: 0x101884d90; "Resume" (activation:inf); id:\M-b\M^@\M-&9D6AF759764B> [active]
}
Jan 17 21:37:44 Owners-iPhone-3 assertiond[74] <Notice>: [MyMobileApp:5966] New process assertion state; preventSuspend, preventThrottleDownUI, preventThrottleDownCPU, preventSuspendOnSleep (assertion 0x100f8a9f0 added: (none); removed: preventIdleSleep)
Jan 17 21:37:44 Owners-iPhone-3 assertiond[74] <Notice>: [MyMobileApp:5966] Setting jetsam priority to 10 [0x10100]
Jan 17 21:37:44 Owners-iPhone-3 assertiond[74] <Notice>: [MyMobileApp:5966] dump all assertions HWM:4 (CPUMON check): {
    <BKProcessAssertion: 0x101884d90; "Resume" (activation:inf); id:\M-b\M^@\M-&9D6AF759764B> [active]
}
Jan 17 21:37:44 Owners-iPhone-3 assertiond[74] <Notice>: Releasing PowerAssertion on MyMobileApp:5966 from update
Jan 17 21:37:44 Owners-iPhone-3 assertiond[74] <Notice>: [MyMobileApp:5966] Remove assertion: <BKProcessAssertion: 0x100f8a9f0; "Called by UIKit, from <redacted>" (finishTask:180s); id:\M-b\M^@\M-&0B8CA7216A0C>
Jan 17 21:37:44 Owners-iPhone-3 assertiond[74] <Notice>: [MyMobileApp:5966] dump all assertions HWM:4 (CPUMON check): {
    <BKProcessAssertion: 0x101884d90; "Resume" (activation:inf); id:\M-b\M^@\M-&9D6AF759764B> [active]
}
Jan 17 21:37:44 Owners-iPhone-3 assertiond[74] <Notice>: -[BKAssertion dealloc] - <0x100f8a9f0>
Jan 17 21:37:44 Owners-iPhone-3 powerd[40] <Notice>: Process assertiond.74 Released SystemIsActive "MyMobileApp:5966:5966-C6CEB4F5-9DCC-4E15-8BB6-0B8CA7216A0C [Called by UIKit, from <redacted>] [0x100f8a9f0]" age:00:00:02  id:51539648155 [System: PrevIdle SysAct]
Jan 17 21:37:44 Owners-iPhone-3 MyMobileApp[5966] <Notice>: [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper start] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:356 :: Starting the request with URL https://myServerIp:443/MyProject/authorization/v1/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=4bd3c60d412b36d16f4da069658c0c7fa226cad1&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmfpredirecturi&isAjaxRequest=true&x=0.15013111462581286
Jan 17 21:37:44 Owners-iPhone-3 MyMobileApp(CFNetwork)[5966] <Notice>: Task <D0C8DF5A-65FD-4BE0-82C9-21579B9947D1>.<0> now using Connection 45
Jan 17 21:37:44 Owners-iPhone-3 MyMobileApp(CFNetwork)[5966] <Notice>: Task <D0C8DF5A-65FD-4BE0-82C9-21579B9947D1>.<0> sent request, body N
Jan 17 21:37:44 Owners-iPhone-3 CommCenter(libATCommandStudioDynamic.dylib)[88] <Notice>: QMI: Svc=0x03(NAS) Ind MsgId=0x0051 Bin=['01 1F 00 80 03 02 04 EB 71 51 00 13 00 14 06 00 C1 F3 A2 FF D4 00 A2 01 00 64 A4 03 00 01 64 00']
Jan 17 21:37:44 Owners-iPhone-3 locationd[71] <Notice>: {"msg":"CLWifiPositioningSystemLogic::apply", "event":"elapsed", "begin_mach":6677197559866, "end_mach":6677197584343, "elapsed_s":"0.001019875", "event":"Motion::CoarseMovement", "now_s":"537935864.721438050"}
Jan 17 21:37:45 Owners-iPhone-3 locationd[71] <Notice>: {"msg":"CLWifiPositioningSystemLogic::apply", "event":"elapsed", "begin_mach":6677205218631, "end_mach":6677205243804, "elapsed_s":"0.001048875", "event":"Motion::CoarseMovement", "now_s":"537935865.040650964"}
Jan 17 21:37:45 Owners-iPhone-3 locationd[71] <Notice>: {"msg":"CLWifiPositioningSystemLogic::apply", "event":"elapsed", "begin_mach":6677220543131, "end_mach":6677220575096, "elapsed_s":"0.001331875", "event":"Motion::CoarseMovement", "now_s":"537935865.679077029"}
Jan 17 21:37:47 Owners-iPhone-3 destinationd(DuetExpertCenter)[5082] <Notice>: predictionForCategories returned error: <private>
Jan 17 21:37:47 Owners-iPhone-3 destinationd(DuetExpertCenter)[5082] <Error>: Error: <private>
Jan 17 21:37:47 Owners-iPhone-3 destinationd[5082] <Error>: <private> received error: <private>
Jan 17 21:37:48 Owners-iPhone-3 symptomsd(SymptomEvaluator)[5571] <Error>: AWD direct: received libnetcore symptom w/ non conforming layout, dropping
Jan 17 21:37:49 Owners-iPhone-3 CommCenter(libATCommandStudioDynamic.dylib)[88] <Notice>: QMI: Svc=0x03(NAS) Ind MsgId=0x0051 Bin=['01 1F 00 80 03 02 04 EC 71 51 00 13 00 14 06 00 C1 F2 A2 FF 8A 00 A2 01 00 64 A4 03 00 01 64 00']
Jan 17 21:37:49 Owners-iPhone-3 locationd[71] <Notice>: {"msg":"CLWifiPositioningSystemLogic::apply", "event":"elapsed", "begin_mach":6677320175459, "end_mach":6677320223146, "elapsed_s":"0.001986958", "event":"Motion::CoarseMovement", "now_s":"537935869.830474019"}
Jan 17 21:37:50 Owners-iPhone-3 locationd[71] <Notice>: {"msg":"CLWifiPositioningSystemLogic::apply", "event":"elapsed", "begin_mach":6677343176271, "end_mach":6677343215897, "elapsed_s":"0.001651083", "event":"Motion::CoarseMovement", "now_s":"537935870.788828015"}
Jan 17 21:37:50 Owners-iPhone-3 backboardd(IOKit)[66] <Error>: iohideventsystem_client_dispatch_properties_changed:0x10004003
Jan 17 21:37:51 Owners-iPhone-3 locationd[71] <Notice>: {"msg":"CLWifiPositioningSystemLogic::apply", "event":"elapsed", "begin_mach":6677350805334, "end_mach":6677350831802, "elapsed_s":"0.001102833", "event":"Motion::CoarseMovement", "now_s":"537935871.106637001"}
Jan 17 21:37:51 Owners-iPhone-3 dataaccessd(PersistentConnection)[574] <Notice>: SimpleTimer <PCSimpleTimer: 0x105abd500> has fired
Jan 17 21:37:51 Owners-iPhone-3 dataaccessd(PersistentConnection)[574] <Notice>: Invalidating simple timer <PCSimpleTimer: 0x105abd500>
Jan 17 21:37:51 Owners-iPhone-3 dataaccessd(PersistentConnection)[574] <Notice>: Disabling power monitoring for <PCSimpleTimer: 0x105abd500> - 2 timers
Jan 17 21:37:51 Owners-iPhone-3 dataaccessd(PersistentConnection)[574] <Notice>: SimpleTimer <PCSimpleTimer: 0x106356790> has fired
Jan 17 21:37:51 Owners-iPhone-3 dataaccessd(PersistentConnection)[574] <Notice>: Invalidating simple timer <PCSimpleTimer: 0x106356790>
Jan 17 21:37:51 Owners-iPhone-3 dataaccessd(PersistentConnection)[574] <Notice>: Disabling power monitoring for <PCSimpleTimer: 0x106356790> - 1 timers
Jan 17 21:37:51 Owners-iPhone-3 MyMobileApp(WebCore)[5966] <Notice>: 0x103313d00 - PerformanceMonitor::measurePostLoadMemoryUsage: Process was using 158139272 bytes of memory after the page load.
Jan 17 21:37:53 Owners-iPhone-3 locationd[71] <Notice>: {"msg":"CLWifiPositioningSystemLogic::apply", "event":"elapsed", "begin_mach":6677396859076, "end_mach":6677396897944, "elapsed_s":"0.001619500", "event":"Motion::CoarseMovement", "now_s":"537935873.025398970"}
Jan 17 21:37:53 Owners-iPhone-3 locationd[71] <Notice>: {"msg":"CLWifiPositioningSystemLogic::apply", "event":"elapsed", "begin_mach":6677404480228, "end_mach":6677404523844, "elapsed_s":"0.001817333", "event":"Motion::CoarseMovement", "now_s":"537935873.342646003"}
Jan 17 21:37:54 Owners-iPhone-3 CommCenter(libATCommandStudioDynamic.dylib)[88] <Notice>: QMI: Svc=0x03(NAS) Ind MsgId=0x0051 Bin=['01 1F 00 80 03 02 04 ED 71 51 00 13 00 14 06 00 BF F5 A3 FF 8C 00 A2 01 00 64 A4 03 00 01 64 00']
```

The request just reaches the web server but it returned with 401 error. Once app is killed and restarted it starts working again.

**IBM Http Server logs**

```
 - - [17/Jan/2018:21:01:12 -0500] "GET /worklightconsole/201704051514/css/images/IBM_logo.png HTTP/1.1" 200 720
 - - [17/Jan/2018:21:01:12 -0500] "GET /worklightconsole/201704051514/css/fonts/bold/helvetica-neue-bold.woff2 HTTP/1.1" 200 30804
 - - [17/Jan/2018:21:11:48 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 283
 - - [17/Jan/2018:21:34:20 -0500] "GET /MYProject/authorization/v1/authorization?client_id=4bd3c60d412b36d16f4da069658c0c7fa226cad1&scope=-MYRealm&isAjaxRequest=true&x=0.275786186755855 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
 - - [17/Jan/2018:21:34:20 -0500] "GET /MyProject/adapters/SecurityAdapter/security/login HTTP/1.1" 401 41
 - - [17/Jan/2018:21:34:21 -0500] "GET /MyProject/authorization/v1/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=4bd3c60d412b36d16f4da069658c0c7fa226cad1&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmfpredirecturi&scope=MYRealm&isAjaxRequest=true&x=0.6627940373520301 HTTP/1.1" 200 25
 - - [17/Jan/2018:21:34:22 -0500] "POST /analytics-service/data HTTP/1.1" 201 -
 - - [17/Jan/2018:21:34:22 -0500] "GET /analytics-service/data/administration/apps/worklight/getSettings HTTP/1.1" 200 1407
 - - [17/Jan/2018:21:34:25 -0500] "POST /MyProject/apps/services/api/MYMobileApp/iphone/login HTTP/1.1" 401 166
 - - [17/Jan/2018:21:34:26 -0500] "POST /analytics-service/data HTTP/1.1" 201 -
 - - [17/Jan/2018:21:36:38 -0500] "GET /MyProject/adapters/AnnouncementsAdapter/announcements/fetchannouncements HTTP/1.1" 401 41
 - - [17/Jan/2018:21:36:40 -0500] "POST /analytics-service/data HTTP/1.1" 201 -
 - - [17/Jan/2018:21:36:40 -0500] "GET /analytics-service/data/administration/apps/worklight/getSettings HTTP/1.1" 200 1407
 - - [17/Jan/2018:21:37:06 -0500] "GET /MyProject/authorization/v1/authorization?client_id=4bd3c60d412b36d16f4da069658c0c7fa226cad1&scope=-MYRealm&isAjaxRequest=true&x=0.410883442826542 HTTP/1.1" 403 19
 - - [17/Jan/2018:21:37:07 -0500] "GET /MyProject/adapters/SecurityAdapter/security/login HTTP/1.1" 401 41
 - - [17/Jan/2018:21:37:08 -0500] "POST /analytics-service/data HTTP/1.1" 201 -
 - - [17/Jan/2018:21:37:44 -0500] "GET /MyProject/adapters/AnnouncementsAdapter/announcements/fetchannouncements HTTP/1.1" 401 41
 - - [17/Jan/2018:21:37:44 -0500] "POST /analytics-service/data HTTP/1.1" 201 -
 - - [17/Jan/2018:21:37:44 -0500] "GET /analytics-service/data/administration/apps/worklight/getSettings HTTP/1.1" 200 1407
 - - [17/Jan/2018:21:34:25 -0500] "POST /MyProject/apps/services/api/MYMobileApp/iphone/login HTTP/1.1" 504 315
 - - [17/Jan/2018:21:34:25 -0500] "POST /MyProject/apps/services/my_custom_auth_request_url HTTP/1.1" 504 315
 - - [17/Jan/2018:21:34:38 -0500] "POST /MyProject/apps/services/api/MYMobileApp/iphone/login HTTP/1.1" 504 315
 - - [17/Jan/2018:21:34:38 -0500] "POST /MyProject/apps/services/my_custom_auth_request_url HTTP/1.1" 504 315
 - - [17/Jan/2018:21:34:53 -0500] "POST /MyProject/apps/services/my_custom_auth_request_url HTTP/1.1" 504 315
 - - [17/Jan/2018:21:34:53 -0500] "POST /MyProject/apps/services/api/MYMobileApp/iphone/login HTTP/1.1" 504 315
 - - [17/Jan/2018:21:34:56 -0500] "GET /MyProject/authorization/v1/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=4bd3c60d412b36d16f4da069658c0c7fa226cad1&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmfpredirecturi&scope=MYRealm&isAjaxRequest=true&x=0.1482186844277551 HTTP/1.1" 504 315
 - - [17/Jan/2018:21:40:04 -0500] "GET /MyProject/authorization/v1/authorization?client_id=4bd3c60d412b36d16f4da069658c0c7fa226cad1&scope=-MYRealm&isAjaxRequest=true&x=0.5411687142084214 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
 - - [17/Jan/2018:21:40:04 -0500] "GET /MyProject/adapters/SecurityAdapter/security/login HTTP/1.1" 401 41
 - - [17/Jan/2018:21:40:06 -0500] "POST /analytics-service/data HTTP/1.1" 201 -
 - - [17/Jan/2018:21:40:06 -0500] "GET /analytics-service/data/administration/apps/worklight/getSettings HTTP/1.1" 200 1407
 - - [17/Jan/2018:21:35:12 -0500] "POST /MyProject/apps/services/api/MYMobileApp/iphone/login HTTP/1.1" 504 315
 - - [17/Jan/2018:21:35:24 -0500] "POST /MyProject/apps/services/my_custom_auth_request_url HTTP/1.1" 504 315
 - - [17/Jan/2018:21:40:33 -0500] "GET /MyProject/adapters/AnnouncementsAdapter/announcements/fetchannouncements HTTP/1.1" 401 41
 - - [17/Jan/2018:21:40:34 -0500] "POST /analytics-service/data HTTP/1.1" 201 -
 - - [17/Jan/2018:21:40:40 -0500] "GET /MyProject/adapters/AnnouncementsAdapter/announcements/fetchannouncements HTTP/1.1" 401 41
 - - [17/Jan/2018:21:40:40 -0500] "POST /analytics-service/data HTTP/1.1" 201 -
 - - [17/Jan/2018:21:40:44 -0500] "GET /MyProject/authorization/v1/authorization?client_id=4bd3c60d412b36d16f4da069658c0c7fa226cad1&scope=-MYRealm&isAjaxRequest=true&x=0.9602466115384183 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
 - - [17/Jan/2018:21:40:45 -0500] "GET /MyProject/adapters/SecurityAdapter/security/login HTTP/1.1" 401 41
 - - [17/Jan/2018:21:40:46 -0500] "POST /analytics-service/data HTTP/1.1" 201 -
```

Comment: I see request timed out in the client side logs and in webserver logs it shows:
 - - [17/Jan/2018:21:34:25 -0500] "POST /MyProject/apps/services/api/MYMobileApp/iphone/login HTTP/1.1" 504 315.

 - - [17/Jan/2018:21:34:25 -0500] "POST /MyProject/apps/services/my_custom_auth_request_url HTTP/1.1" 504 315
This means gateway timeout.

This points to network/timeout issues. Is the call from webserver not reaching the Appserver?
Also, you mention immediately after direct update. Does this happen after reloading the application following direct update ?

Comment: That's Correct it happens following direct update. And sometimes if the application is kept in the background. I also see this error [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:390 :: Response Error : The request timed out.

Comment: This error is not passed back to the caller method.

Comment: In the case of application in background and then accessing, does the application always fail to connect, once you bring it back to foreground? Or is this only one instance and thereafter it starts working? Also, is your server running on session dependent mode?

Comment: When we bring the app to the foreground  after some gap, it will definitely fail and the only way to fix is to kill the app and start again, then it works. And yes we are running server in Session dependent mode.

Comment: Even though we run in session mode the scenario I am describing is not happening after logging in or something. It happened even before logging in.

Comment: @VivinK Do you think this might be my issue. In authenticationConfig.xml we have all login module set to expires in 3600 seconds. Our server is running in session dependent mode with session timeout set to 16 min. We also have custom login module and its token expires in 3600 seconds.

Comment: In that case, your call will result in a 401 ( post session expiry). However, this will not a connectivity issue. Connection has to succeed before server challenges again.

Comment: I think that's what I am getting 401. Correct me if I am wrong, with our custom realm MFP have multiple other wrapped realm which is authenticated first?

Comment: @VivinK I have created a PMR for this issue.